# jquery grabs the previous value instead of current one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I cannot make jquery to grab the current value of textarea. I have several posts and each of them has "write a review" button. When I select on the button of first post, it shows the dialog box with **first post** title and a textarea. When I write something in the appeared textarea and press submit, it alerts **nothing**. Then I am clicking the same button on the first post and it shows me dialog box with the **title of second post** and when I type something in the textarea and press submit, it alerts the text which I typed in the **previous dialog box**. Could you please have a look on my code and help me to find my mistake.

Here is my view:

```
$data = array(
    'name' => $places_id,
    'class' => 'review',    
    'content' => 'Write a Review'    
    );
   echo form_button($data);

<div id="write_review">
  <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
  <textarea rows='6' cols='90' maxlength='600' id="review_text"></textarea>
  </div>
```

Here is my JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".review").click(function () {
        var self = this;
        var places_id_review = $(self).attr("name");
        $("#write_review").dialog({
            title: "Write a Review",
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            width: 600,
            height: 300,
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Submit',
                click: function () {
                    var review_text = $("#review_text").val();
                    alert(review_text);
                    $.post('filter/post_review', {
                        places_id_review: places_id_review,
                        review_text: review_text
                    }, function (data) {
                        alert("ok")
                    }, "json");
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Cancel',
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close')
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because there are duplicates of your dialog in DOM
at least you can get your value like this:

```
var review_text = $("#review_text", this).val(); //to prevent lookup in while DOM
```

But you better control your dialog's duplicates( using 'destroy' on close event 'close'):

```
$(".review").click(function () {
    var self = this;
    var places_id_review = $(self).attr("name");
    $("#write_review").dialog({
        title: "Write a Review",
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        width: 600,
        height: 300,
        close:function(){ $(this).dialog('destroy'); },  // DELETE dialog after close
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Submit',
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close'); // do not forget close after submit
                var review_text = $("#review_text").val();
                alert(review_text);

                $.post('filter/post_review', {
                    places_id_review: places_id_review,
                    review_text: review_text
                }, function (data) {
                    alert("ok")

                }, "json");
            }
        }, {
            text: 'Cancel',
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help! Now it grabs the current value and posts it, but when i click on the "write review" button of the **second post** it shows the dialog box for the **previous post** (title and review) even though we have destroyed the previous dialog box on closing.